# jQuery wrap syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-wrap

It's end of day. I'm hoping I'm just having a lapse of logic.

I can't get this to work:

```
var $divA= $("<div></div>").addClass('classA');

var $divB= $("<div></div>").addClass('classB');

$myDiv.after($divA.wrap($divB));
```

The above should turn this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Into this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div class="classB">
    <div class="classA"></div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to work with that 'wrap' in there. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't wrap divA with divB and just inserts divA by itself.

Am I misunderstanding wrap?

UPDATE:

A simpler example that does not work:

```
$myBox.after($("<p></p>").wrap("<div></div>"));
```

That will add just the DIV after myBox.

It seems like jQuery doesn't like wrap added to after.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
$myDiv.after($divA.wrap('<div class="divB"></div>'));
```

just for testing purposes?

As far as I understand, you shouldn't pass a jQuery object to the wrap-function:

> The .wrap() function can take any
>   string or object that could be passed
>   to the $() factory function to **specify
>   a DOM structure**. This structure may be
>   nested several levels deep, but should
>   contain only one inmost element. The
>   structure will be wrapped around each
>   of the elements in the set of matched
>   elements.

If the example above works, then this is the reason ;-)

Comment: Good to know! Alas, even by just making it a string, I still can't get it to work (see new example in my post)

Comment: It DOES take a jQuery object, since $() factory can take it.
Take $( $('<div/>') ) for example

Comment: @DénesPapp, you're right... it *should* take it, but it doesn't.  that is to say, it will accept it but it won't do anything useful with it.  stupid, stupid.  should be better documented

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled onto this thread having the same problem: [jQuery .wrap() isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569922/jquery-wrap-isnt-working)

I think if you change your code from

`$myDiv.after($divA.wrap($divB))` to `$myDiv.after($divA.wrap($divB).parent())`

you'll get your wrap.

Answer (score 2):

The confusing part might have been to You that `.wrap()` returns the inner element, not the parent element.

So you have to use the **parent** object of the wrapped one like this:

```
var $divA= $("<div/>").addClass('classA'),
    $divB= $("<div/>").addClass('classB');

$myDiv.after($divA.wrap($divB).parent());
```

(`$divA.parent()` is equal to `$divB` after the wrapping)

So the key part is that `$divA.wrap($divB)` returns `$divA`, NOT `$divB`

see the reference:

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining
>   purposes.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work:

```
$('div#myDiv').after("<div class='classA'></div>").end().find('.classA').wrap("<div class='classB'></div>");
```

with your html to solve your initial question.  [Here](http://api.jquery.com/end/)'s the source for jQuery's end function.  This code will go make the chain go up one level (to the myDiv level), and will then wrap based on the find('.classA') at that level.  That will find your div added with after, and wrap it in div with classB.

Edit:
Ok, I think this will work for you the way you want:

```
var divA= $("<div></div>").addClass('classA');
$('div#myDiv').after($(divA).wrap('<div class="divB" />'));
```

I think the problem was that when calling wrap on divA, it needs to be a jQuery object to work correctly.  So really all you were missing was wrapping divA in ().

Comment: That's my fallback, but I'm trying to avoid having to traverse things again.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking for wrap. You want:

```
divB.append(divA).insertAfter('#myDiv');
```

Comment: I'll up vote that as that would seem to accomplish the same thing. Nice! I'm still curious as to why the wrap method I use only partially works. It seems like it should do what I'm intending or should fail outright.

Comment: you got an up vote just because you'd been down voted.  I hate people that down vote without feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading this wrong, but if you're using jQuery, isn't the $ a reserved character? have you tried just setting your variable names so they don't use it?

If so:

```
var divA = $("<div></div>").addClass('classA');
divA.wrap("<div class=\"classB\"></div>");
divA.insertAfter($("#myDiv"));
```

or

```
divA.after($("#myDiv"));
```

[Here's the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/after/) on the matter.

Comment: There's a bit of a debate as to whether or not to do that but many people preface any variable that is a jQuery object with the $

Comment: Wow didn't know that. Looks like PHP or Perl!

Comment: you confuse $divA with $(divA). They are not the same. And $divA is also not the same as $, they are like A and B, two separate variable names