# jQuery .wrap() isn't working

Tags: jquery

I'm probably doing something wrong but I've tried all sorts of things and can't seem to get a collection of jQuery objects wrapped. The following just outputs the link HTML, unwrapped. Any ideas?

```
$.each(sitemapSections, function(i) {
  var $sitemapSection = $(sitemapSections[i]);
  var $primary = $sitemapSection.find('a[data-level="1"]').wrap('<h3></h3>');

  $dropdownSections[i].html($primary);
});
```

EDIT - here's the markup (cleaned up):

```
<li id="product-solutions"><a href="#link" class="alpha grid-6">Products &amp; Solutions</a>

  <div id="ps-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu grid-20">
    <div class="ps-dropdown-section">

    </div><!-- .ps-dropdown-section -->

    <div class="ps-dropdown-section">

    </div><!-- .ps-dropdown-section -->

    <div class="ps-dropdown-section">

    </div><!-- .ps-dropdown-section -->
  </div><!-- .dropdown-menu -->
</li>
```

UPDATE - I got it! The comments who mentioned parent() is what I was missing. Here's the final code:

```
$.each(sitemapSections, function(i) {
  var $sitemapSection = $(sitemapSections[i]);
  var $primary = $sitemapSection.find('a[data-level="1"]').wrap('<h3></h3>').parent();

  $dropdownSections[i].html($primary);
});
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

jquery .wrap() returns the INNER element back to you, so it looks like nothing changed.

```
$("<div>").wrap('<span>') 

===> 

[<div></div>]
```

which looks like it didn't work.

**but:**

```
$("<div>").wrap('<span>').parent()

===>

[<span><div></div></span>]
```

it actually did work.

Comment: There should be example in jQuery docs! It's written: `This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes` but it's hard to figured out that `parent()` is helpful when you want get "new object"

Comment: @instead agreed.  If what you're wrapping is already in the DOM and you're leaving it there, wrap is intuitive.  If you're wrapping some elements you just generated that aren't in the DOM yet and want to insert the tag you just wrapped your selection with it's not so clear.

Comment: I lost a lot of time trying to know why this did not work >:c

Comment: You can use `.wrapInner()` to get the result you expect

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mean to use jQuery's html method to add html in the second to last line - unless $dropdownSections is an array with each element being a jQuery object. I think you might be after this:

```
$.each(sitemapSections, function(i) {
  var $sitemapSection = $(sitemapSections[i]);
  var $primary = $sitemapSection.find('[data-level="1"]').wrap('<h3></h3>');

  $dropdownSections.eq(i).html($primary.parent().html());
});
```

or more written another way:

```
$.each(sitemapSections, function(i) {
  $dropdownSections.eq(i).html(
    $(sitemapSections[i])
    .find('[data-level="1"]')
    .wrap('<h3></h3>')
    .parent()
    .html()
  );
});
```

if $dropdownSections is an array which has a jQuery object in each element:

```
$.each(sitemapSections, function(i) {
  $dropdownSections[i].html(
    $(sitemapSections[i])
    .find('[data-level="1"]')
    .wrap('<h3></h3>')
    .parent()
    .html()
  );
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as it strips out the link. but to answer you question, yes this is a collection. So i need each anchor wrapped in an <h3>

Also, it didn't wrap it in an <h3> either...

Comment: you're right! that wrap didn't work. after wrapping you should be able to go to the parent element (which would be the <h3> tag at that point) to get the html.

Answer (score 0):

You need a string to pass into [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), I think you're after this instead:

```
 $dropdownSections[i].empty().append($primary.parent());
```

This gets the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) (since you just wrapped it in one) and sets the contents to that.

Comment: this didn't do anything. still the same :(

Comment: @CoryDorning - Oh, duh, my fault, you need to use `.parent()` since you just wrapped it :)

Comment: where does the wrapping occur?

Comment: @CoryDorning - `.wrap('<h3></h3>')` doesn't return the `<h3>`, it returns the element that you wrapped in the `<h3>`, if you want to append the actual `<h3>`, toy need to call `.parent()` :)

Comment: @Nick you lost me man...the code you have above doesn't wrap each element of $primary in an <h3>. That's what I need.

Comment: @CoryDorning - The above above is meant to replace only your `$dropdownSections[i].html($primary);` line, not the other 2...